# Apache wicket breadcrumb on one page

Tags: java, html, apache, wicket, breadcrumbs

I would like to create breadcrump on my page, but I am unable to do it by following wicket examples.. I need to extend BreadCrumbPanel when I also need to extend WebPage..

I want breadcrumb to be visible only on this specific page, after clicking some of links on the page(they call setresponsepage with some parameters) I would like to append my breadcrumb

```
public final class GroupMainPage extends WebPage {

 //    Map<String, Group> hostGroup = PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getHostGroupMap();
 List<Group> hostGroup = PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getHostGroupList();

public GroupMainPage() {
    super();
    HostGroupManager.getInstance();
    createMainTable(hostGroup);
          add(new Label("message", "OK \n ok"));
}
```

then I have some methods which help me create table on my page, especially this one with links where I would like to append my breadcrumb:

```
        ListView<Component> list = new ListView<Component>("groupListElement", ((Group) component).getDependentGroups()) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<Component> item) {
                final Component c = item.getModelObject();
                Link link = new Link("groupLink") {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick() {
                        Group g = (Group) c;
                        if (g.getDependentGroups() != null && g.getDependentGroups().size() > 0) {
                            setResponsePage(new GroupMainPage(g.getDependentGroups()));
                        } else {
                            setResponsePage(new GroupServiceListPage(g.createServicesList()));
                        }
                    }
                };
                link.add(new Label("linkLabel", c.getName()));
                item.add(link);
```

How to make it possible?

Comment: no an actual answer but i would recommend use javascript and cookies(maybe sessionstorage) for that job, in my experience it result a lot easier